# Unity www.progress always return 0

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine

Unity 5.3.4p1
Mac OS X 10.11.5

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class TestWWW : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers["Api-key"] = "sorry-i-cant-post-this";
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        string url =  "http://sorry-i-cant-post-this";
        var req = string.Format(
            "{{\"major\":{0},\"minor\":{1},\"patch\":{2},\"release\":{3},\"notice\":{4}}}",
            0, 0, 0, 40, 0
        );
        byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(req);

        var www = new WWW(url, postData, headers);
        StartCoroutine(F(www));
    }

    IEnumerator F(WWW www) {
        while(!www.isDone) {
            Debug.Log(www.progress);
            yield return null;
        }
        if(www.error == null)
            Debug.Log("Done");
        else 
            Debug.Log(www.error);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

This code always print 0, because while loop of F(WWW www) function cant finish.

I use Charles to monitor, find the Response Code is 405 Method Not Allowed.

and the request is

```
POST /api/client/v2 HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: UnityPlayer/5.3.4p1 (http://unity3d.com) Host: http://sorry-i-cant-post-this Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: identity Api-key: sorry-i-cant-post-this Content-Length: 55 Content-Type: application/json X-Unity-Version:
5.3.4p1

{"major":0,"minor":0,"patch":0,"release":40,"notice":0}
```

Is there any thing wrong?

Or it is just a Unity bug?

Thanks!!!

Finally, I find it's because I open ShadowSocks.

Comment: Did you write the server code?

Comment: @Programmer of course! I even use postman to test server is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the server is not returning the **content length header**. In your server code, you should add the header `Content-Length:` followed by the size of the data you are sending to the client.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then use the `UnityWebRequest` API. Ported the code in your question to use `UnityWebRequest`  instead of `WWW`.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    string url = "http://sorry-i-cant-post-this";
    var req = string.Format(
        "{{\"major\":{0},\"minor\":{1},\"patch\":{2},\"release\":{3},\"notice\":{4}}}",
        0, 0, 0, 40, 0
    );

    UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post(url, req);
    www.SetRequestHeader("Api-key", "sorry-i-cant-post-this");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    StartCoroutine(F(www));
}

IEnumerator F(UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www)
{
    www.downloadHandler = new UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.Send();

    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadProgress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Done");
        Debug.Log("Downloaded: " + www.downloadHandler.text);

        // Or retrieve results as binary data
        byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
```

Comment: in != NULL
UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking.DownloadHandler:get_text()
<F>c__IteratorE:MoveNext() (at Assets/TestWWW.cs:42)

Comment: @mingchaoyan updated my answer. the first error you mentioned should be gone now. Also understand that I provided two answers. If the second one fails, try the first one. So far you have only tried one.

Comment: Assets/TestWWW.cs(27,96): error CS0122: `UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking.DownloadHandler.DownloadHandler()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @mingchaoyan I am using Unity 5.4 not 5.3. Try it with Unity 5.4 where `UnityWebRequest` is no longer in experimental mode. Also you have not tried the first method I listed.

Comment: ok. I am trying to download 5.4. The server programmer is not here right now, so, your first one may can not try right now.

Comment: I asked in the question comment **Did you write the server code?** and you said yes. Anyways, when he arrives show him this post and he may be able to understand what I mean by putting the length header in the server code. Let me know what happens when you download 5.4 https://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your *write*. I mean I have *run* a server. I can see the server log. When using postman server prints log. But when I use www no log printed.  And use your UnityWebRequest there is a log too.

Comment: @mingchaoyan I thought your problem is that  `www.progress` is always 0 but everything else work. I need to see the server php or whatever server language code to be able to help further more.

Comment: @mingchaoyan Found the error **UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking.DownloadHandler.DownloadHandler()' is inaccessible due to its protection level**. Updated my answer again. Just re-copy it. Also realize that I may not be able to help any further without seeing the server code if this doesn't work. It worked on my side after I tested this edit.

Comment: use DownloaderBuffer() is the same error    in != NULL
UnityEngine.Experimental.Networking.DownloadHandler:get_text()
<F>c__IteratorE:MoveNext() (at Assets/TestWWW.cs:43)

Comment: @mingchaoyan This should work. Is this now fixed? Also I looked in your updated question and saw `Host: http://sorry-i-cant-post-this` This means that you did not change `Host: http://sorry-i-cant-post-this` to the server url. You are suppose to change `Host: http://sorry-i-cant-post-this` to the server url.